# Linear algebra. commutative algebra, a matrix having the maximal rank

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra

I found a matrix that looks to have the maximal rank for my research.

I would really appreciate if some of you could give me any comments or suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Sincerely, Yong-Su Shin

Let $s,t\ge 3$ and let $t-2=\ell+\delta$ with $\ell\ge 1$, and let $a_i$ and $b_i$ be all variables and $k$ be a field of characteristic $0$.

We define the matrix $A_\delta(s,t,\ell+1)$ with $0\le \delta \le t-3$ as follows.

$$
A_0(s,t,\ell+1,\delta)=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \cdots & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
  & \vdots & & & \ddots & &\ddots & & \ddots \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 1 & \cdots & 1  
\end{bmatrix}_{(\ell+1)\times s(\ell+1)} .
$$
Here $\ell+1$ is the number of column block matrices.

$$
A_1(s,t,\ell+1,\delta)=
\left[\begin{matrix}
a_1 & \cdots & a_s  & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0  \\
b_1 & \cdots &b_s & a_1 & \cdots &a_s  & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0  \\
 0 & \cdots & 0 & b_1 & \cdots & b_s & a_1 & \cdots &  a_s  & 0 & \cdots & 0  \\
  & \vdots & & & \ddots & & & \ddots & & & \ddots & \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0   \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0   
\end{matrix}\right. \\
\left.\begin{matrix}
 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0  & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
 & \ddots & & & \ddots & &   & \ddots & & & \vdots \\
 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & b_1 & \cdots & b_s  & a_1 & \cdots &  a_s  \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 &  b_1 & \cdots & b_s   
\end{matrix} \right]_{(\ell+2)\times s(\ell+1)} 
$$

In general
$$
\begin{array}{lllll}
     A_{\delta}(s,t,\ell+1,\delta) 
:= & 
\begin{array}{llllllll} 
\left[
\begin{matrix} 
a_1^{\delta} & \cdots & a_s^{\delta}  & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0   \\
a_1^{\delta-1}b_1 & \cdots & a_s^{\delta-1}b_s & a_1^{\delta} & \cdots &a_s^{\delta}  & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0   & \\
& \vdots && & \vdots  && & \vdots   && 0 & \cdots & 0   \\
b_1^{\delta} & \cdots & b_s^{\delta}  & a_1b_1^{\delta-1} & \cdots & a_sb_s^{\delta-1} & & \cdots & &
a_1^{\delta} & \cdots & a_s^{\delta}     \\
  & \vdots & & & \ddots & & & \ddots & & & \ddots     \\
  0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0  & 0 & \cdots & 0    \\
  & \vdots & & & \ddots & & & \ddots & & & \ddots    \\  
0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0    \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0  
\end{matrix} \right.  
\end{array} 
\\ 
& \hskip .64 cm \begin{array}{llllllll} 
\left.\begin{matrix} 
 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots &  0 &  0 & \cdots   & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0& 0 & \cdots & 0  \\
 & \vdots  && & \vdots  && & \vdots  &&&\vdots \\
 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
 & \ddots & &   & \ddots & & & \ddots &&& \vdots  \\
 0 & \cdots & 0 & b_1^{\delta} & \cdots & b_s^{\delta} & &\cdots &  & a_1^{\delta-1}b_1 & \cdots &  a_s^{\delta-1}b_s & a_1^{\delta} & \cdots & a_s^{\delta} \\
 & \ddots & &   & \ddots & & & \ddots &&& \ddots  \\  
  0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 &  b_1^{\delta} & \cdots & b_s^{\delta} &  a_1b_1^{\delta-1} & \cdots &   a_sb_s^{\delta-1}  \\
 0 & \cdots & 0 &  0 & \cdots & 0 &  0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & b_1^{\delta} & \cdots & b_s^{\delta}
\end{matrix} \right]
\end{array} 
\end{array}
$$
where $A_{\delta}(s,t,\ell+1) $ has the size $(\alpha+\beta+1)\times s(\ell+1)$ with $\alpha+\beta=\ell+\delta\le t-2$.

We now define the matrix
\begin{equation}\label{EQ:202201227-101} 
\begin{array}{llllllllllllll}
A(s,t,\ell+1,\delta)
& := & 
\begin{bmatrix}
A_0(s,t,\ell+1,\delta) \\ A_1(s,t,\ell+1,\delta) \\ \vdots \\ A_{\delta}(s,t,\ell+1,\delta)
\end{bmatrix}_{\gamma\times s(\ell+1)} 
& = & \begin{bmatrix}
A_0(s,t,\ell+1) \\ A_1(s,t,\ell+1) \\ \vdots \\ A_{(t-2)-\ell}(s,t,\ell+1)
\end{bmatrix}_{\gamma\times s(\ell+1)} 
\\
& := & 
\begin{bmatrix}
C_1(s,t,\ell+1,\delta) & \cdots & C_{\ell+1}(s,t,\ell+1,\delta)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{array}
\end{equation}
where $C_k(s,t,\ell+1,\delta)$ is the $k$-th  $\gamma\times s$ column block matrix of $A(s,t,\ell+1,\delta)$ and
$$
\gamma=(\ell+1)+\cdots +(t-1)=\binom{t}{2}-\binom{\ell+1}{2}.
$$
Note that the $(k+1)$-st column block matrix $C_{k+1}(s,t,\ell+1,\delta)$ is the matrix that remains after we add $0$-row vector at the top of the matrix $C_k(s,t,\ell+1,\delta)$ and remove the bottom $0$-row vector of the matrix $C_k(s,t,\ell+1,\delta)$ for $1\le k \le \ell$.

**Conjecture:**
The matrix $A(s,t,\ell+1,\delta)$ has the maximal rank for $s\ge t\ge 3$ and $t-2=\ell+\delta$ with $\ell\ge 1$.

**Example.**
$$ 
\begin{array}{lrlllllllll}
A(6,6,1+1,3)
& := & 
\begin{bmatrix}
A_0(6,6,1+1,3) \\ A_1(6,6,1+1,3)   \\ A_2(6,6,1+1,3) \\ A_3(6,6,1+1,3)
\end{bmatrix}_{14\times 12} \\
& = & 
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|ccccccccccccccccccccccc}
1 & \cdots & \boxed{1} & 0 & \cdots  & 0 \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & \cdots  & \boxed{1} \\ 
\hline 
a_1 & \cdots  & a_s & 0 & \cdots   & 0 \\
b_1 & \cdots & \boxed{b_s} & a_1 & \cdots  & a_s  \\
0  & \cdots  & 0 & b_1 & \cdots  & \boxed{b_s} \\
\hline 
a_1^2 &  \cdots & a_s^2 & 0 &  \cdots & 0 \\
a_1b_1 &  \cdots & a_sb_s & a_1^2 &  \cdots & a_s^2  \\
b_1^2 &  \cdots & \boxed{b_s^2} & a_1b_1 &  \cdots & a_sb_s \\
0  &  \cdots & 0 & b_1^2 &  \cdots & \boxed{b_s^2} \\ \hline 
a_1^3 &  \cdots & a_s^3 & 0 &  \cdots & 0 \\
a_1^2b_1 &  \cdots & a_s^2b_s & a_1^3 &  \cdots & a_s^3  \\
a_1b_1^2 &  \cdots & a_sb_s^2 &  a_1^2b_1 &  \cdots & a_s^2b_s \\
b_1^3 &  \cdots & \boxed{b_s^3} & a_1b_1^2 &  \cdots & a_sb_s^2 \\
0  &  \cdots & 0 & b_1^3 &  \cdots & \boxed{b_s^3} 
\end{array}\right] 
\end{array} 
$$
has the maximal rank.

**Example.**
$$
\begin{array}{lrlllllllll}
A(8,8,2+1,4)
& := & 
\begin{bmatrix}
A_0(8,8,2+1,4) \\ A_1(8,8,2+1,4)   \\ A_2(8,8,2+1,4) \\ A_3(8,8,2+1,4) \\ A_4(8,8,2+1,4)
\end{bmatrix}_{25 \times 24} \\
& = & 
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc | ccc | ccc  ccccccccccccccccc}
1 & \cdots & \boxed{1} & 0 & \cdots  & 0 & 0 & \cdots  & 0 \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & \cdots  & \boxed{1} & 0 & \cdots  & 0 \\ 
0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & \cdots  & \boxed{1} \\
\hline 
a_1 & \cdots  & a_s & 0 & \cdots   & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
b_1 & \cdots & \boxed{b_s} & a_1 & \cdots  & a_s  & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0  & \cdots  & 0 & b_1 & \cdots  & \boxed{b_s} & a_1 & \cdots  & a_s \\
0  & \cdots  & 0 & 0  & \cdots  & 0 & b_1 & \cdots  & \boxed{b_s} \\
\hline 
a_1^2 &  \cdots & a_s^2 & 0 &  \cdots & 0 & 0 &  \cdots & 0 \\
a_1b_1 &  \cdots & a_sb_s & a_1^2 &  \cdots & a_s^2  & 0 &  \cdots & 0 \\
b_1^2 &  \cdots & \boxed{b_s^2} & a_1b_1 &  \cdots & a_sb_s & a_1^2 &  \cdots & a_s^2 \\
0  &  \cdots & 0 & b_1^2 &  \cdots & \boxed{b_s^2} & a_1b_1 &  \cdots & a_sb_s \\ 
0  &  \cdots & 0 & 0  &  \cdots & 0 & b_1^2 &  \cdots & \boxed{b_s^2} \\
\hline 
a_1^3 &  \cdots & a_s^3 & 0 &  \cdots & 0 & 0 &  \cdots & 0  \\
a_1^2b_1 &  \cdots & a_s^2b_s & a_1^3 &  \cdots & a_s^3  & 0 &  \cdots & 0  \\
a_1b_1^2 &  \cdots & a_sb_s^2 &  a_1^2b_1 &  \cdots & a_s^2b_s & a_1^3 &  \cdots & a_s^3  \\
b_1^3 &  \cdots & \boxed{b_s^3} & a_1b_1^2 &  \cdots & a_sb_s^2 & a_1^2b_1 &  \cdots & a_s^2b_s \\
0  &  \cdots & 0 & b_1^3 &  \cdots & \boxed{b_s^3} & a_1b_1^2 &  \cdots & a_sb_s^2 \\  
0  &  \cdots & 0 & 0  &  \cdots & 0 & b_1^3 &  \cdots & \boxed{b_s^3} \\ \hline
a_1^4 &  \cdots & a_s^4 & 0 &  \cdots & 0 & 0 &  \cdots & 0 \\
a_1^3b_1 &  \cdots & a_s^3b_s & a_1^4 &  \cdots & a_s^4   & 0 &  \cdots & 0 \\
a_1^2b_1^2 &  \cdots & a_s^2b_s^2 &  a_1^3b_1 &  \cdots & a_s^3b_s & a_1^4 &  \cdots & a_s^4 \\
a_1b_1^3 &  \cdots & a_sb_s^3 &  a_1^2b_1^2 &  \cdots & a_s^2b_s^2  &  a_1^3b_1 &  \cdots & a_s^3b_s \\
b_1^4 &  \cdots & \boxed{b_s^4} & a_1b_1^3 &  \cdots & a_sb_s^3 &  a_1^2b_1^2 &  \cdots & a_s^2b_s^2 \\
0  &  \cdots & 0 & b_1^4 &  \cdots & \boxed{b_s^4} & a_1b_1^3 &  \cdots & a_sb_s^3 \\
0  &  \cdots & 0 & 0  &  \cdots & 0 & b_1^4 &  \cdots & \boxed{b_s^4}   
\end{array}\right] 
\end{array} 
$$
has the maximal rank.

**Remark.** The following cases are verified by myself.

1. Let $s\ge t=6$. Then the matrix $A(s,6,\ell+1,\delta)$ has the maximal rank for such $s$.
2. Let $s\ge t=7$. Then the matrix $A(s,7,\ell+1,\delta)$ has the maximal rank for such $s$.
3. Let $s\ge t=8$.

(3-1) If $(\ell,\delta)=(6,0), (5,1), (4,2), (3,3)$, then the matrix $A(s,8,\ell+1,\delta)$ has the maximal rank for such $s$.

(3-2) Let $s\ge 8$ with $(\ell,\delta)=(2,4)$. Then the matrix $A(8,8,2+1,4)$ has the maximal rank.

(3-3) If $8 \le s\le 11$ with $(\ell,\delta)=(1,5)$, then the matrix $A(s,8,2+1,4)$ has the maximal rank for such $s$.

(3-4) **If $12\le s \le 15$ with $(\ell,\delta)=(1,5)$, then it is unknown**.

(3-5) If $s\ge 16$ with $(\ell,\delta)=(1,5)$, then the matrix $A(s,8,1+1,5)$ has the maximal rank for such $s$.